# Llamar una función JAVASCRIPT desde HTML

Tags: javascript, html

Éste es el codigo de la vista

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="funciones.js"></script>
<link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

</head>
<body>

<div class="slideshow-container">

<div class="mySlides fade">
  <div class="numbertext">1 / 3</div>
  <img src="1.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <div class="text">Caption Text</div>
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade">
  <div class="numbertext">2 / 3</div>
  <img src="1.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <div class="text">Caption Two</div>
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade">
  <div class="numbertext">3 / 3</div>
  <img src="1.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <div class="text">Caption Three</div>
</div>

<a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
<a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>

</div>
<br>

</body>
</html>
```

Y tengo un archivo JS en donde tengo las funciones

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}


function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
      dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
}

});
```

Ahora me marca este error cuando hago click en el elemento "a"

> Uncaught ReferenceError: plusSlides is not defined
>       at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick (prro.html:33)

Alguna solución?

Comment: funciones.js se encuentra en la misma carpeta que la pagina?

Comment: si allí se encuentra

Comment: Si estas usando Jquery, porque no lo invocas desde ahi con `$('.prev').on('click', function(){})`

Comment: Ya lo intenté pero no hace nada, no marca error, pero no hace nada, de hecho le puse un alert dentro de la función pero nada

Comment: Gracias pero ya funcionó

Comment: @ErnestoEmmanuelYahLopez Puedes colocar la respuesta a tu pregunta, para así próximos usuarios que tengan el mismo problema sepan la solución.

Comment: @Theia: Stack Snippet sólo debe agregarse cuando se puede ejecutar el código. En este caso al hacer clic la consola muestra errores. Por lo anterior voy a revertir la edición que realizaste.

Comment: Gracias @Rubén, lo tendre en cuenta para la proxima

Comment: @Ernesto: Cuando se va a hacer una pregunta sobre código que no funciona deben seguirse las indicaciones de [mcve].

Comment: llegué aqui por tu medalla de oro. Alguna de las respuestas merece ser marcada como aceptada? Un saludo

Comment: Muchas gracias por recordame, una disculpa a los que respondieron, en un momento pongo las aceptadas, disculpa

Comment: que programa estan usando para editar ambos codigos?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Un par de cosas.
Primero, los funciones deben estar afuera del document.ready.
segundo el variable slideIndex es un variable global entonces pertenece afuera tambien.
Asi:

```
var slideIndex = 1;
function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}


function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
      dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    showSlides(slideIndex);
});
```

Comment: Puedes explicar por que deben ir afuera las funciones?

Comment: Puedes explicar por que deben ir afuera las funciones?  porfavor

Comment: Lo que tienes adentro del document.ready tienen que correr despues que la pagina ha cargado completamente. si estan afuera de document.ready estan disponibles cuando la pagina esta lista.

Comment: @Simon: Deberías [editar] tu respuesta para incluir a explicación que has dado como comentario ya que estos son temporales.

Answer (score 2):

En javascript el ambito de las funciones y las variables son las funciones, es decir, que para poder acceder a una funcion o variable debe estar definida en su mismo `scope`. Por ejemplo:

```js
function outterFunction() {
  function innerFunction() {
    return 3;
  }
  console.log(innerFunction());
}

outterFunction();
console.log(innerFunction());
```

esto falla, pues `innerFunction` solo esta definida dentro de la funcion `outterFunction`.

De la misma forma para poder llamar a una funcion de javascript desde html deberia estar en el mismo scope, que en este caso es el scope global. Para definir las funciones en el scope global solo tienes que definirlas afuera de cualquier funcion como la funcion `outterFunction` del ejemplo anterior

```js
function outterFunction() {
  console.log(3);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="outterFunction()">Click me </button>
```

Igual destacar que el scope esta definido por las `funciones` y no por las llaves `{ }`, se puede mostrar en el siguiente ejemplo

```js
{
  var a = 6;

  function c() {
    return "hello from the function";
  }
}
console.log(a);
console.log(c());
```