# mostrar una variable de Javascript en HTML

Tags: php, javascript, java, html

Lo que busco es que me quede algo parecido a esto
[image: Lo que busco es que me quede algo parecido a esto]

El codigo que tengo es este

Esta es la parte de la funciones

```js
 function can_x2(){
      var cantx2 = (quantity * 2)  ; 
      return (cantx2);
    }
    function can_x4(){
      var cantx4 = (quantity * 4)  ; 
      return (cantx4);
    }
```

```html
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="Assets/css/bootstrap.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="Assets/css/estyles.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="Assets/css/fontawesome.min.css" />
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lato:ital,wght@1,900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <title>Elabels - Quotes</title>

</head>

<body>

          <div class="align-self-center w-100 px-lg-5 py-lg-4 p-4">
            <h1 class="font-weight-bold mb-4">Get A Quotes</h1>

            <!--- Inicio del form -->
            <form class="row g-3" method="post" action="">
              <div class="col-md-4">
              <label for="width">Width</label>  
                             <input type="number" name="width" id="width" class="form-control" min="1" max="13"  step="any" required>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-4">
              <label for="height">Height</label>    
                             <input type="number" name="height" id="height" class="form-control" required step="any" min="1" max="25">
              </div>

              <div class="col-md-4">
              <label for="quantity" >Quantity</label>   
                             <input type="number" name="quantity" id="quantity" class="form-control" required   min="1" >
              </div>

              
    
    
    
    <span>la cantidad es <?php echo $cantx2 ?></span>
    
 </body>
```

Basicamente lo que busco es podes que la cantida que se esta haciendo el la operacion mejor dicho el resultado de esta me pueda dar el resultado si el cliente pone 5 que la cantx2 se muestre en el span o label o si es en un boton radio mucho mejor. Las operaciones me funcionan perfectamente en la consola me da los resultados pero al momento que yo quiero mostrar en la pantalla ya del cliente me sale que esa variable no esta definida

Comment: Para mostrar una variable de Javascript en HTML tienes que llamarla con innerHTML, mira el enlace [Llamar Funcion JS en HTML](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/83991/llamar-una-funci%C3%B3n-javascript-desde-html)

Comment: Gracias, pero no entiendo bien como le tendria que hacer  @Nor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

revisando tu codigo puedo ver que estas tratando de imprimir una variable de PHP `<?php echo $cantx2 ?>`, sin embargo toda tu logica esta en JS ese es el primer error.

El segundo error de tu codigo es que en ningun momento estas instanciando al elemento `quantity` en el JS.

Tambien para lograr imprimir tus variables dentro del cuerpo de HTML debes hacerlo con [innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML), teniendo eso en mente tu codigo debe quedar de la siguiente manera

```js
let quantity = document.getElementById("quantity");
let toShow = document.getElementById("toShow");

quantity.addEventListener('change', can_x2);

function can_x2(){
  var cantx2 = (quantity.value * 2)  ; 
  toShow.innerHTML = "La cantidad es: "+cantx2;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="Assets/css/bootstrap.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="Assets/css/estyles.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="Assets/css/fontawesome.min.css" />
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lato:ital,wght@1,900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <title>Elabels - Quotes</title>

</head>

<body>

          <div class="align-self-center w-100 px-lg-5 py-lg-4 p-4">
            <h1 class="font-weight-bold mb-4">Get A Quotes</h1>

            <!--- Inicio del form -->
            <form class="row g-3" method="post" action="">
              <div class="col-md-4">
              <label for="width">Width</label>  
                             <input type="number" name="width" id="width" class="form-control" min="1" max="13"  step="any" required>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-4">
              <label for="height">Height</label>    
                             <input type="number" name="height" id="height" class="form-control" required step="any" min="1" max="25">
              </div>

              <div class="col-md-4">
              <label for="quantity" >Quantity</label>   
                             <input type="number" name="quantity" id="quantity" class="form-control" required   min="1" oninput="can_x2(this.value)">
              </div>

              
    
    
    
    <span id="toShow"></span>
    
 </body>
```